# Computing height of water level in tank given dimensions, size of hole and gravity?

Tags: calculus, applications

I was given a question involving creating a function for the height of the water level in a tank, given gravity, the size of the hole in the tank and dimensions of the tank, as identified here.

[image]

I am completely unsure as to where to start for this problem, and possibly the correct answer will help me backtrack as to how to approach the question.

Comment: are we assuming the water falls out according to bernoulli's principle?

Answer (score 1):

You need to relate the volume of water to depth and time. To relate to depth, if we look at a circular cross section of the tank with the origin at the bottom and the $y$-axis pointing up, the equation for the circle is $x^2+(y-R)^2=R^2$ where $R$ is the tank's radius. Then the for a given depth $y$, $x=\pm\sqrt{R^2-(y-R)^2}=\pm\sqrt{2Ry-y^2}$, so the width of the surface of the water in the tank is $2\sqrt{2Ry-y^2}$ and its length is $L$, so if we piled water on top with extra thickness $dy$ the extra volume would be $dV=L\sqrt{2Ry-y^2}dy$. We have the relationship between volume and depth that we wanted,
$$\frac{dV}{dy}=L\sqrt{2Ry-y^2}$$
Assuming water flows without viscous losses it should follow Bernoulli's equation
$$p_1+\frac12\rho v_1^2+\rho gy_1=p_2+\frac12\rho v_2^2+\rho gy_2$$
Where $p_1=p_2=P_{\text{atmospheric}}$ for both the surface of the water and for the free-flowing stream of water. Also the water is moving very slowly at the surface in the tank, so take $v_1=0$. Then $y_1-y_2=y$ is the depth of water in the tank, so we are down to
$$\rho gy=\frac12\rho v^2$$
with $v_2=v$, the speed of the stream flowing out of the hole. In a small period of time $dt$ a volume of water with cross-sectional area $B$ and length $v\,dt$ flows out of the hole so
$$dV^{\prime}=Bv\,dt=B\sqrt{2gy}dt$$
flows out of the hole so the rate of increase of volume is
$$\frac{dV}{dt}=-\frac{dV^{\prime}}{dt}=-B\sqrt{2gy}$$
Knowing $\frac{dV}{dy}$ and $\frac{dV}{dt}$ we can find $\frac{dy}{dt}$ and integrate. The solution comes out as
$$t_e=\frac{2L}{B\sqrt{2g}}\left(\frac{12\,\text{in}}{1\,\text{ft}}\right)^2\cdot\frac23R^{3/2}\left(2^{3/2}-1\right)\approx18502.4\,\text{sec}$$
By my calculation.